# Flutter Smart refresher doesnot hiding after loading completed

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

Below is my dart code used to make pull up to load more option in my chat application. I have a problem that when I pulled up the chat once then the chat will be reloaded, but the **words under text type box** are not hiding automatically.  A screenshot of my chat view is shown in the attached image. How I can hide those words automatically after the loading completed. Someone, please help me.
Thank you.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G18M0.jpg)

```js
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 1000), () => _controller.jumpTo(_controller.position.maxScrollExtent));
    return new WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: _onWillPop,
        child: new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: Text(name),
      ),
      body: SmartRefresher(
          enablePullUp: true,
          enablePullDown: false,
          controller: _refreshController,
          onLoading: getChat,
          child: _saving?new Stack(
            children: [
              new Opacity(
                opacity: 0.3,
                child: const ModalBarrier(dismissible: false, color: Colors.grey),
              ),
              new Center(
                child: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
              ),
            ],
          ):new Container(
            child: new Column(
            children: <Widget>[
            new Flexible(
              child:new ListView.builder(
//                reverse: true,
//                shrinkWrap: true,
                controller: _controller,
                itemCount: msg_list == null ? 0 : msg_list.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  if (msg_list[index]["NoMessageFound"] != null) {
                    return Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new ListTile(
                          title: Text("No Messages"),
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                  } else {
                    label = msg_list[index]["body"];
                    var sign;
                    if (msg_list[index]["direction"] == "outbound") {
                      return createOutboundTile(label,msg_list[index]["time"]);
                    } else {
                      return createInboundTile(label,msg_list[index]["time"]);
//
                    }

                  }
                },
              ),
            ),
            new Divider(height: 1.0),
            new Container(
              decoration:
              new BoxDecoration(color: Theme.of(context).cardColor),
              child: _buildTextComposer(),
            ),
            new Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
//              _scaffoldContext = context;
              return new Container(width: 0.0, height: 0.0);
            }),
            ],
          ),
              decoration: Theme.of(context).platform == TargetPlatform.iOS
              ? new BoxDecoration(
              border: new Border(
                  top: new BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.grey[200],
                  )))
              : null,),
      )
    ));
  }
```

```js
  Future<Null> getChat() async {
    setState(() {
      _saving = true;
    });
    String did = await SharedPreferencesHelper.getDidValue();
    String user_name = await SharedPreferencesHelper.getUserName();
    String usr_pwd = await SharedPreferencesHelper.getUserPassword();
    http.post("http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx/r_p_a_p/get_single_chat.php",
        body: {
          "username": user_name,
          "password": usr_pwd,
          "did": did,
          "number" : "1"+number
        }).then((response) {
          _refreshController.loadComplete();
      this.setState(() {
        _saving = false;
      });
      if (response.statusCode != 200) {
        _showdilog(context, "Server failed to respond.");
        return "failed";
      }
      var jsonResponse = convert.jsonDecode(response.body);
      if (jsonResponse["result"]) {
        this.setState(() {
          msg_list = jsonResponse["list"];
        });
         timer = new Timer.periodic(new Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
          refreshMessage();
        });
      } else {
        this.logout();
      }
      if(_controller.hasClients) {
        _controller.jumpTo(_controller.position.maxScrollExtent);
      }
      return "Success";
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to notify the `SmartRefresher` that the loading is done, call `_refreshController.loadComplete();` when your data loaded.

Comment: I have already notified the loading is done to SmartRefresher with the above-specified code. But it's not hiding it's 'Pull up Load More' Comment. Please help me, thank you.

Comment: Can you update your code please ? i need to see how you used loadComplete

Comment: You can see, in my above code, I am calling the getChat function at onLoading of SmartRefresher. I have used the `_refreshController.loadComplete();` inside that function . I have just updated my question by including my getChat function.

Comment: How did you instantiate _refreshController ?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you. Please explain. Can we discuss this via email?. This is my email ID faris@nethram.com

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

```
footer: const ClassicFooter(
                        loadStyle: LoadStyle.ShowWhenLoading),
```

This will help you.
You just need to change default property of loadStyle.

Answer (score 1):

For those who use "onRefresh" callback, be careful to use "refreshController.refreshCompleted()" stead of "refreshController.loadComplete()"